# Why does Adam Chlipala use left-associated nested tuples to represent Ltac lists in CPDT?

Tags: list, coq, ltac

Via [`CpdtTactics.v`](http://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/hritcu/dyn/coind/CpdtTactics.html):

> [...] Succeed iff `x` is in the list `ls`, represented with left-associated nested tuples.
>
> `Ltac inList x ls :=
>   match ls with
>     | x => idtac
>     | (_, x) => idtac
>     | (?LS, _) => inList x LS
>   end.`

This seems atypical. Doesn't the tail of the list conventionally go in the right-hand side of the tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow n-tuples are nested pairs associated to the left:

```
(x, y, z)
```

desugars to

```
pair (pair x y) z
```

And that's what we get if we want to write `inList x (x, y, z)`.

Answer (score 3):

Via private communication with Adam:

> No, I can't think of any way to prefer one version over the other, 
>   actually.  I just had to make some choice for that part of the book.